# Get MethodInfo of method labeled with custom Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, system.reflection

I am decorating class methods with a custom `TriggerHandler` attribute.

```
public class TriggerHandlerAttribute : Attribute
{

  #region Data Members

  public readonly Type EntityType;

  public readonly TriggerType TriggerType;

  #endregion

  #region Constructor

  // Current constructor
  public TriggerHandlerAttribute( Type entityType, TriggerType eventType )
  {
     EntityType = entityType;
     EventType = eventType;
  }

  // Example of the desired implementation
  public TriggerHandlerAttribute()
  {
    // 1. Somehow obtain MethodInfo
    // 2. Configure attribute based on MethodInfo's parameters (already implemented)
  }

  #endregion

}

[TriggerHandler(typeof(SomeType), TriggerType.Basic)]
private void SomeMethod( ITriggerBasic<SomeType> triggerContext )
{
  ...
}
```

I would like to be able to define a parameter-less constructor for this attribute and use reflection to fill in the fields, but to do this, I need to be able to access the `MethodInfo` of the method that is decorated with this attribute.

Is there a way to obtain the `MethodInfo` of the method that  the particular `TriggerHandlerAttribute` is assigned to? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean get the `MethodInfo` inside your attribute's constructor?

Comment: Attributes should be immutable, and treated as such when they're not. If you need to apply defaults, apply them when you query the attribute for the purpose you intend.

Comment: @dcg Yes. I have added an example usage to the post. In that example, I would like to obtain the `MethodInfo` of `SomeMethod` inside of the attribute's constructor.

Comment: @madreflection The attribute will be immutable. I would just like to automatically configure the attribute inside of its constructor based on the method that it is being applied to.

Comment: @Haus As fas as I know, there's no way to do that. Attributes are just metadata on what they decorate. But I might be wrong :)

Comment: It's unclear what you intend to do. If you don't know where to start, maybe add some pseudocode.

Comment: I think I get it now. **No**, an attribute cannot find the code element to which it has been applied.

Comment: There is no way for an attribute to know what it has been applied to.

Comment: Circling back to and expanding on my earlier comment... to do what you want, when you find the attribute applied to a method, detect that it was not configured with those values (e.g. the `EntityType` property is `null`) and use the `MethodInfo` instance (the source of the attribute) to get the values you need.

Comment: A helpful point to note may be that a new instance of the custom attribute is constructed every time `GetCustomAttributes` is called i.e. you might as well compute the `Type` and `TriggerType` at that time.